# Xamarin - image saved to gallery without date

Tags: date, xamarin, gallery, save-image

I use this code to save images to the gallery:

```
       Uri uri = new Uri(baseUrl + imageName);
       var img = await ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(baseUrl + "social/social_" + imageName).AsJPGStreamAsync(quality:100);

       string fileName = "Social_" + uri.ToString().Split('/').Last();

       DependencyService.Get<IMediaService>().SaveImageFromStream(img, fileName);
       await DisplayAlert("Saved", "Image saved to gallery!", "Ok");
```

the problem is, that the images do not have a time in the file, and are stored randomly in the gallery...

How can I add date to the files, so they are saved in the proper order in the gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Just append something like this

`DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss");`

```cs
string fileName = "Social_" + uri.ToString().Split('/').Last() + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmss");
//03312020071656
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I do not want to rename the file based on time.. I want to add the time to the file properties so that it is put correctly in the gallery.. i BELIVE it is the file's exif data that is taken into account..

Comment: post the code for creating and saving the file platform wise for both iOS and Android. Gallery as in built in app? app should have feature of **Sort** by time, only then it will show it chronologically, by default file would have creation time i think. if not please show the metadata of a file of your concern to the post